# What is the relationship between "quantum coherence" and "coherent states"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, decoherence, coherent-states

What is the relationship between Quantum coherence and Coherent States?

I (almost) get the concept of Quantum Coherence when i think about it in the framework of density matrices.
I also get the concept of Coherent states, as special states of the quantum harmonic oscillator.

But when i think about the relationship between those two concept I get lost.
I have a masters in physics, so i have a foundation to stand on.

Can someone help me? This is my first question on stackexchange, sorry if i made some mistakes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there isn't a strong relation. One talks of "quantum coherence" to essentially refer to the property of quantum systems of allowing for superposition states. Better said, given a choice of measurement basis, one has "coherence terms" when the state is a superposition of the eigenstates of the measurement. In this sense, every (pure) state is "coherent" with respect to some basis.

On the other hand, a "coherent state" is a specific kind of many-boson state. This state exhibits "quantum coherence", and has a bunch of properties that make it of interest.

Loosely speaking, one might say that a system is "loosing coherence" to refer to (*e.g.*) environmental noise making it harder to detect interference effects. What this means precisely will vary widely between contexts and physical systems.

Comment: I feel that this overlooks a lot of history. The name "coherent states" isn't accidental - it was coined (iiuc) by Glaube when he was studying the quantum mechanical underpinnings of *optical* coherence. The rest of the relationship mostly follows obviously from there.

Comment: '...every (pure) state is "coherent" with respect to some basis.' By implication, a bad choice of basis would make a pure state seem incoherent, right? Can you give an example?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty sorry, just saw this. I can't tell what you're objecting to exactly though. History aside, what would you say the relationship is, apart from coherent states being, well coherent (with respect to the "natural in this context" Fock basis)? Or are you just saying that there is a tight historical relation?

Comment: @flippiefanus trivially, any pure state $|\psi\rangle$ has no coherence in any basis that includes $|\psi\rangle$